# JavaFX change single style in CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, javafx, colors, stylesheet

I've created a small text editor window that allows the user to change some basic properties of a text area included within the screen. Two of the options available to change the properties of the textArea are font color and font color fill, which are both handled by separate color pickers.

I ran into an issue when testing these buttons using the setStyle method that only one property could be saved at a time. Example, if text color was set to BLUE, and afterwards fill color was set to YELLOW, text color would not remain blue, but instead revert back to its default defined in the stylesheet (black).

To fix this problem, I have created the following method;

```
  private void updateTheSyle()
    {
        this.textArea.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: " + toRgbString(this.colorPickerFill.getValue()) +
                "; -fx-text-fill: " + toRgbString(this.colorPickerFont.getValue()) + ";");
    }
```

The toRgbString() method is also called, this is simply passing the user input from the color picker into a string such that the setStyle method can pass the correct parameters to the stylesheet.

This solution does work, as it enables me to change both the fill and the font color without reverting back to default upon selection. However, my program includes more than just fill and font color, which will contribute to a far longer setStyle statement as these options are added.

**TLDR**: Is there a way to edit a single style included in a CSS stylesheet without affecting the other styles in a given class?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question (*longer setStyle statement*), If we take into account that the style is defined by a `String`, and it takes a whole set of details to provide for a single Style, so why not use a `List<String>` :

```
List<String> example = new ArrayList<>();
String style = "";

//For example if you use 2 textField to get the (value) and (type):
example.add("-fx-"+textFieldType+":"+textFieldValue + "; ");

//To gather all the properties in a single string
for(String property: example){

   style += example;
}

yourNode.setStyle(style);
```

I do not know if there is a better approach but it works, good luck !

**Edit :**

I think this tip answers your second question:

```
private void Update(String type,String newValue){

    for(int i = 0; i < example.size(); i++){

        if(example.get(i).contains(type)){

            example.set(i, "-fx-"+type+":"+newValue + "; ");
            //Here you add a (break;) to not alter the other similar styles !
        }

    }   

   //Here you use a loop to update the new elements changed

}
```

I hope this will help you solve your problem !

Comment: Interesting work around, your method takes care of the concatenation nicely, but still doesn't allow for single lines to be effected in a CSS sheet. I'm not sure how this would handle multiple inputs, i.e. the font color is changed more than once, as the method you have created simply adds to a list array rather than updating the value of the style property